# Setting Up GCP VPC for Integromat

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc, make.com

The goal is to allow Integromat to connect to our GCP CloudSQL MySQL instance. Usually what I've been doing to allow an IP address to access a GCP resource is to add the authorized IP as a public IP authorized network in the resource's Connectivity tab directly on the resource's page.

On the integromat help center however, they are requesting access for a range of IP's which I find no way of setting up under Connectivity. So I'm starting to look at VPC network configuration with a limited understanding of networking.

```
Integromat makes connections from the following IP range: 82.208.14.110 - 82.208.14.119. Our servers are set up with valid PTR records so you can easily restrict access by allowing %.integromat.com.
```

I'm wondering how using GCP's Virtual Private Cloud setup what is the right process to allow that IP range so that Integromat can have incoming and outgoing access to our project and mainly CloudSQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty certain you are reading an exam question, etc. as an experienced network engineer would not choose that address range. A better choice is either starting at 82.208.14.112 or 82.208.14.96. Networks work best when bitmasks can be applied.

You need to make two entries in the Cloud SQL Authorized networks.

- 82.208.14.110/31
- 82.208.14.112/29

Cloud SQL expects network address ranges to be in CIDR notation. There is no single CIDR that covers the total range of x.x.x.110 to x.x.x.119. Therefore more than one CIDR is required.

[Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)

Comment: Thank you so much John. Your suggestion seems to work.

Comment: @DavidHaddad - You are welcome. I do this every day, so it fairly easy.